# Logging all web trafic

Tags: networking, server, 18.04

I have fresh Ubuntu 18.04 with all updates. There are two network cards. One for internet connection. The second is to distribute this Internet over a local network.

It is necessary for my to keep all logs of visited sites. From which ip in the local network to which Internet address did someone visit and when (date and time). It is necessary that it works in the background all the time. And automatically started after server reboot. Ideally, it should be logs, automatically shared by day and archived as syslogs.

Comment: Too difficult and there is a far more simple method:  use the log from the router.

Comment: @Rinzwind `netfilter/iptables` - it is difficuls and bad too?

Comment: Thing is: if someone has physical access he/she can do -anything- by just rebooting into a live session. But they can not access the router if you keep the password for that safe.

Comment: @Rinzwind , physical  - it is not important. Only local network

Comment: What are on about? "physical - it is not important" and "Only local network" are unrelated. This "It is necessary for my to keep all logs of visited sites." is only 100% reliable to do from the log of your router. All other methods you can work around your logging if you know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a proxy server (squid, apache or nginx) and your loggin is generated automatically.

This is easy and good way. Also you can do this to cache, so bandwith need is reduced.

For setup for eg. squid in ubuntu server:

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/squid.html.en

Comment: thansk! The main question is - do I need to configure something extra on client machines? Now the client machines are configured - ip address, subnet mask and ip address of the server. After installing the squid (using your link) need I to specify a proxy server on client machines?

Comment: No. You can serve proxy server via dhcp, so no configuration on client side is not required.

Comment: By static configuration of the network you need to specify proxy in clients.

Comment: it is Transparent Proxy? But what about https? dhcp - we can't use it. every client matchine mast have static ip

Comment: you see only https traffic, not contents. There is reason for S in HTTPS. And yes, squid is transparent proxy.